# Keep all proto files in one folder and access specific one in proto_library() in bazel

Tags: protocol-buffers, bazel

I want to specify the proto srcs like below so that all  protos coming from different folks for the project can live under one folder. I am not able to

```
proto_library(
    name='addressbook',
    srcs=['proto/addressbook.proto']
)

cc_proto_library(
    name='cc_addressbook',
    deps=[':addressbook']
)

cc_binary(
    name='write',
    srcs=['write.cpp'],
    deps=[':cc_addressbook']
)

cc_binary(
    name='read',
    srcs=['read.cpp'],
    deps=[':cc_addressbook']
)
```

Should I create a filegroup with srcs=["addressbook.proto"] in the proto/BUILD file instead and add it as dependency to
proto_library ?, am new to bazel so am confused on how to pass right srcs[] value to proto_library function and what include path I shud have in my write.cpp, read.cpp so the generated headers get included correctly. Thanks

The example source code for the project is in https://github.com/bakkiraju/protobuf_bazel_test

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to have a `proto/BUILD` file, you should put the `proto_library` there. Instead of that, if you remove `proto/BUILD`, then what you have above should work. Doing anything else isn't really how the C/C++ and Protobuf rules for Bazel are set up and it will fight you.

When writing Bazel BUILD files, you should almost always use source files from rules in the same [package](https://bazel.build/concepts/build-ref#packages) (ie folder with a BUILD file and all its subfolders without BUILD files). If you want to use them from other packages, [`filegroup`](https://bazel.build/reference/be/general#filegroup) and [`exports_files`](https://bazel.build/reference/be/functions#exports_files) are the easy options. `filegroup` groups up a bundle of source files (and/or rule outputs) and gives them a new [label](https://bazel.build/concepts/labels). `exports_files` just makes files visible from other packages directly.

Putting rules in different packages from their source file makes it harder to see violations of the [One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) (basically each symbol must be defined in exactly one place, but there's a ton of nuance). From past experience, violating that makes really weird things happen, like the code segfaults when run normally but works fine under gdb. I believe the C/C++ rules have a warning for this reason.

As far as what `srcs` does in general, the `srcs` attributes of most rules (including `cc_library` and `proto_library`) will grab the [default outputs](https://bazel.build/extending/rules#default_outputs) from everything you specify. For source files, this is just the files. For rules, this is extracted from the [`DefaultInfo.info`](https://bazel.build/rules/lib/DefaultInfo#files) [provider](https://bazel.build/extending/rules#providers) field. Any exceptions to this, and what the default outputs are, are specific to each rule.